# python checker lines for json file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, python-requests

I have a `json` file:

```
{
  "alreadyScraped": [
        {
              "name": "ahmed  Red",
              "card_number": "4859430145105235",
              "expiration_date": "07/20 619",
              "address": "54 7ron St",
              "city": "RoGester",
              "state": "NY",
              "zip": "14619",
              "country": "US"
        }
  ]
}
```

I have also a file txt

```
ahmed  Red
454544887788
07/10 719
54 7ron St
RoGester, NY 45619 US
rrzo  ted
485985540145105235
07/50 619
54 grn St
Rorhter, NY 14419 US
foko  Red
477879430145105235
10/10 809
54 rtgn St
Rorgster, NY 1th19 US
```

here my code fix it please, I want it to check if that text exist in json file or not that's all I want.

```
clean = []
file = open("text.txt","r").readlines()
for lines in file:

    clean.append(lines.strip())

for i, line in zip(cycle(range(5)), clean):
            if i ==0:
                  vvc_info = { here the checker!
                        "name":clean[0],
                        "card_number":clean[1],
                        "expiration_date":clean[2],
                        "address":clean[3],
                        "city":clean[4].split()[0].replace(',', ''),
                        "state":clean[4].split()[1],
                        "zip":clean[4].split()[2],
                        "country":clean[4].split()[3]  }
            if not vvc_info in db["alreadyScraped"]:
                                print(vvc_info["name"])
```

Comment: What do you want fixing? Is there some sort of error, or does it not print the right thing?

Comment: I want to make it, checks 5 lines of code in the json file, if there is exist i want it to print hello, if not i want it to print anythin. that's it the code is totally wrong, but it helps a littel

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
import json

file = open("textfile.txt", "r")
clean = []
for lines in file.readlines():
    clean.append(lines.strip())

x = {
    "alreadyScraped": {
        "name":              clean[0],
        "card_number":       clean[1],
        "expiration_date":   clean[2],
        "address":           clean[3],
        "city":              clean[4],
        "state":             clean[5],
        "zip":               clean[6],
        "country":           clean[7]  
    }
}


# Parse to JSON
y = json.dumps(x)
z = json.loads(y)

print(z['alreadyScraped']['name'])
```